# Kotlin Pass Variable to New Activity

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-studio

I am very new to Kotlin and Android, and am currently trying to get an app to pass data from an EditText field to another activity. However, when I fill out the EditText field and hit the button to go the next activity, instead of displaying what I typed, it displays:

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{6f725 8d VFED..CL. ........ 66,66-1014,184 #7f0801f3 app:id/companyNameText aid=1073741824}
```

The code I have for activity one is:
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="25dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/companyNameText"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Enter Your Company Name"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnActivity2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#048AC8"
        android:text="Go to activity 2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Kotlin:

```
package com.example.finalprojectmichaeldebernardi

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnActivity2)
            .setOnClickListener {
                val companyName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.companyNameText).toString()
                val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("companyName", companyName
                )
                startActivity(intent)
            }
    }
```

And the code I have for the second activity is:
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="25dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/companyName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Kotlin:

```
package com.example.finalprojectmichaeldebernardi

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import org.w3c.dom.Text

class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

        val companyName = intent.getStringExtra("companyName")

        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.companyName).apply {
            text = companyName
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In other words, replace `val companyName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.companyNameText).toString()` with `val companyName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.companyNameText).getText().toString()`